# Return non-aggregates along with aggregates in Linq select

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to convert the basic SQL query into Linq.

The aggregates are returning fine, but the non-aggregates are not.

SeriesId, Amount, and NumberOfTrades are perfect.

Code and Isin aren't causing errors, but they're returning the type rather than the data.

The query I'm trying to convert:

```
SELECT
  trans_series.id, 
    trans_series.number,
    trans_series.isin,
    SUM( trans_trades.amount ),
    COUNT( trans.series_id ) 
FROM
    trans_trades
INNER JOIN trans_series ON trans_series.id = trans_trades.series_id 
WHERE
    trans_trades.series_id  IN (
    17,
    18)
    AND trans_trades.first_party_id IS NULL
    AND trans_trades.status <> 'closed'
    AND trans_trades.status <> 'cancelled'
    GROUP BY trans_trades.series_id
```

The method:

```
public List<TotalByIsinViewModel> GetIssuerSeries()
        {
            _context = new MySQLDatabaseContext();
            
            var result = (from ts in _context.TradesSeries
                         join tts in _context.TradesTrades
                         on ts.Id equals tts.SeriesId
                         where myInClause.Contains(tts.SeriesId)
                         group new { ts, tts } by new { tts.SeriesId } into g
                         select new TotalByIsinViewModel
                         {
                             SeriesId = g.Key.SeriesId,
                             Code =  g.Select(i => i.tts.Number).Distinct().ToString(),
                             Isin = g.Select(i => i.ts.Isin).Distinct().ToString(),
                             Amount = (decimal?)g.Sum(pt => pt.tts.Amount),
                             NumberOfTrades = g.Count()
                         }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

The view model:

```
    public class TotalByIsinViewModel
    { 
        public int SeriesId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Isin { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfTrades { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm expecting the actual distinct varchar values from the "number" and "isin" columns, but I'm getting type data returned in my Razor page's cs Onget.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
Code =  g.First().tts.Number,
Isin = g.First()ts.Isin,
```

And the reason is in `g.Select(i => i.tts.Number)` you select a list of values.
Maybe you have only one value in list but C# still sees a list.
And `ToString` method for arrays is inherited from `Object` class. So it prints type name.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem by changing the "Isin" and "Code" to this:

```
   Code = g.Select(i => i.ts.Number).Distinct().First(),
   Isin = g.Select(i => i.ts.Isin).Distinct().First(),
```